# Why is the sorted() method on Stream not named sort()?

Tags: java, api, api-design, stream-processing

Why is the sorted() method on Stream not named sort()?

```
list.stream().sort()
```

Comment: Probably because it returns a sorted *copy* of the list instead of sorting it in place.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--), the `sorted()` method is a ***stateful intermediate operation.***

You can read more about what that means [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> **Intermediate operations return a new stream.** They are always *lazy;* executing an intermediate operation such as `filter()` does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, *when traversed,* contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate.

So `sorted()` *describes the new stream* created by the sorted() method, not the act of sorting.

Comment: The grammar makes sense but is inconsistent with _map_, _filter_, etc. I guess it's a legitimate question to ask why there is that discrepancy.

Comment: I guess the main reason is that there is already an interface with a `sort` method in the JRE, and that `sort` method sorts in-place. Having a lazy, non-destructive method *also* called `sort` would be confusing.

Comment: There are Collections.sort() and List.sort(). Stream.sorted() is very confusing.

Comment: @Abe: In C#, the corresponding method is `.OrderBy()`, which returns a new *sequence* in the specified order.  It is still lazy and it is still an "intermediate operation."